# accept nested attributes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a nested form but I'm missing something as keep getting an error.

--configuration model

```
class Configuration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :configoptions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :configoptions
end
```

--show configuration view

```
<%= form_for @config do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :configoptions do |fp| %>
    <p>
      <%= fp.label :name %>
      <%= fp.text_field :name %>
    </p>
  <% end %>    
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

According to some online guides i've found this should work. but I keep getting an error:

```
undefined method `configuration_path' for #<#<Class:0x2549dac>:0x2548f88>
```

Does anyone know a way to make this work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your routes are configured incorrectly. The following line:

```
<%= form_for @config do |f| %>
```

creates a form tag to post your new/updated object to. In this case, it would look for `configuration_path` as the default path for a new object form. Use `rake routes` to see if there is a listing similar to this

```
configurations GET    /configurations(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"configurations"}
               POST   /configurations(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"configurations"}
```

or look for `resources :configurations` in your `config/routes.rb`. (If not, add `resource :configurations`). If you get confused by routing, check out the corresponding Rails Guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Alternatively, you can specify a different URL to post the action to, by passing the `:url` argument to your form helper:

```
<%= form_for @config, :url => some_other_path do |f| %>
```